# Error resolving template only when run from jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app in STS. When I run it from IDE, everything works fine. However, when I create a jar using *mvn clean install* I get: Error resolving template /login when I try to launch the app. Here is my config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();
}
```

and:

```
*@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("/login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);      
    }
}*
```

Comment: what happens when you remove the leading '/' in setViewName?

Comment: Great Success! thx mate!